# Scribble programming in gtk3

Tags: gtk, cairo, gtk3

How to use gtk-3 to build a scribble program.I found example in gtk-3 official website ,but while drawing it uses the cairo_rectangle to draw the user input. it very very slow compare to  gtk_draw_lines()in gtk-2. Cairo funcions cannot be able to capture data pixel by pixel.

what i want , is there any function in gtk-3 to draw very faster ,able to capture (x,y) point and draw that point by pixel to pixel in my draw area?

Comment: Well, a pixel is basically a rectangle of size 1×1. Which tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: here gtk -3 [example] (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-getting-started.html) ...although it draws using cairo rectangle functions but there is big lack in that,...help with some alternatives

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `gdk_draw_lines` tells it's deprecated, because all the drawing has been delegated to cairo a long time ago. The documentation tells that you may use `cairo_line_to` to connect your points, and `cairo_stroke` to draw a line between those points.

**ADDENDUM:**

Cairo is a vector graphics library: by design and on purpose, it's not designed to do pixel per pixel access. However you may trick it by changing your transformation matrix so that it reflects your pixel coordinates. Give a look at the [CTM (Current Transformation Matrix) modification functions](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html), in particular [`cairo_scale`](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html#cairo-scale). You may catch the `configure-event` of your `GtkDrawingArea` to be notified when its size changes and have a chance to modify the CTM accordingly.

Comment: I have also tried with cairo_line_to and cairo_stroke to draw in draw area .yet the same problem ,not capable of drawing pixel by pixel....

Comment: I just added information on how you could do some kind of pixel-per-pixel access.